# How to add floating point in lcd num for Qt?

Tags: floating-point, pyqt5, qt5, qt-creator, qt-designer

In Qt designer i try to add floating point between the digits like 19.44 but i haven't find any functionality to do it. To do this i have write a simple code given below:

this is want i wanna do:

[image: lcd display of Temperature 19.44]

I want to show a temperature value. for this i tried writing float(8.8) and it approximate it to 9. i want to show it like 8.8. here is my .py file.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(469, 360)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("")
        Dialog.setSizeGripEnabled(False)
        Dialog.setModal(False)
        self.lcdNumber_2 = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Dialog)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 60, 191, 161))
        self.lcdNumber_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.lcdNumber_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setSmallDecimalPoint(True)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setDigitCount(2)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setSegmentStyle(QtWidgets.QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setProperty("intValue", 88)
        self.lcdNumber_2.setObjectName("lcdNumber_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image: lcd display of '9']

How to add a point in it? is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider that QLCDNumber is a *very* old widget that is still available for backward compatibility, it lacks transparent support for complex values or specific notation and it often has unexpected behavior. Consider using a simple QLabel and look for a LCD-style font to set for it.

The behavior is indeed ambiguous at least in Designer, so, first of all use the `value` property (which accepts floating point numbers) and not the `intValue`, and increase the value of `digitCount` to at least 5, since the decimal point counts as a digit when rounding values (4 numbers + decimal point).

Then, whenever you need to set a value in your program, instead of using the number, use its string representation:

```
    self.lcdNumber_2.display('{:.02f}'.format(value))
```

<sup>Maybe you already know it, but better safe than sorry: remember that pyuic generated files should *never* be modified, so the above line should be implemented for your program in a *new* main script, following the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand how to use it.</sup>

Comment: yes, its working.

Comment: @samannaz good. But remember that if an answer solves your problem you should not say that in a comment, but mark the answer as accepted instead, by checking the gray tick on its left. Please review the [tour] to better understand how SO works.